# How to compile a BlueZ application for ARM-Linux (IMX6UL)?

Tags: c, linux, arm, embedded-linux, bluez

I want to cross compile an application from my workstation (x86, linux) for an ARM application processor.
still now ,I have finished these as blow:

1, for PC ,Ubuntu 16.04，it supports BlueZ already ,I  can use Bluetoothctl\hcitool\hciattach in Ubuntu now.

2, for ARM,Linux 4.1 ,it supports BlueZ too,I  can use Bluetoothctl\hcitool\hciattachin ARM CHIP.

---

my demo code is from 
https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html

the function of the code below is to scan Bluetooth device .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, sock, len, flags;
    int i;
    char addr[19] = { 0 };
    char name[248] = { 0 };

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
    if (dev_id < 0 || sock < 0) {
        perror("opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    len  = 8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));

    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
    if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");

    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
        ba2str(&(ii+i)->bdaddr, addr);
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        if (hci_read_remote_name(sock, &(ii+i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name), 
            name, 0) < 0)
        strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
        printf("%s  %s\n", addr, name);
    }

    free( ii );
    close( sock );
    return 0;
}
```

i build code above by

## gcc -o simplescan simplescan.c -lbluetooth

it is successfully 
i got a binary(X86 PC) and i can use it to driver Bluetooth dongle to scan my own cellphone in PC.

still this step ,everything is good ,but I want build this code for ARM, 
so I change the gcc --->arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
I have test this toolchain already ,for a "helloword" and 'read UART',using this toolchain is no problem .

**but when I do # arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-o simplescan simplescan.c -lbluetooth. get something wrong.**

it shows asm/xxx.h NO such file. (xxx here means so many files ).

I try to use CMD "locate" to search this asm/xxx.h file ,but there are so many asm/xxx.h file with the same name in my PC ,how can I select suitable one? DO I need ARM-Linux source code to build ?

I have no idea  now ,please  help me , thank you very much !

Comment: You can compile with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --sysroot=</path/to/arm/sysroot/ -o ./bin/simple ./simple.c -lbluetooth`. Here the sysroot path should contain both the bluez related libraries, includes and also libc + system libraries. You can also use DBUS API as detailed here: https://www.linumiz.com/bluetooth-adapter-scan-for-new-devices-using-startdiscovery/.

Comment: thank you veryyyyyyyyyy much！！！！I use the BSP of imx6ul ，set the  sysroot to the BSP ，then compile is successfull ！

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer of Parthiban！
I set the sysroot to the bsp，then successfully！

you should make sure that Bluetooth.so is exist in the BSP， and the head file below also！
bluetooth.h  cmtp.h  hci_lib.h  l2cap.h   sco.h  sdp_lib.h
bnep.h       hci.h   hidp.h     rfcomm.h  sdp.h

ask Freescale or other chip vendor to get a yocto toolchain for your ARM chip！

root@yjppc:/a_work# $CC -o simplescan simplescan.c --sysroot /opt/myir-imx-fb/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/ -lbluetooth
root@yjppc:/a_work# ls
apps material simplescan simplescan.c